# Microsoft / Botbuilder for NodeJS: Bind URL Parameters to bot session

Tags: node.js, botframework

### SDK

- Homepage: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder
- SDK Platform: Node.js
- SDK Version: 3.14.0

### Issue Description

Hi, I searched for this for a long time now but I haven't found an answer.
I was wondering if there is a way to bind some URL parameters to the User's Bot Session.
For example, if for a specific chat dialog, I set my Endpoint URL to:

```
http://localhost:3978/api/messages?pronuntiation=british
```

is there a way to get that url parameter named "pronuntiation" down in the session object like...

```
bot.dialog("/", function(session){
    var desiredPronuntiation = session.someUrlParameters.pronuntiation;
    if( desiredPronuntiation == "british"){
          ///blah
    }
});
```

I think it is possible in C# SDK but I was trying to do this in NodeJS...

I already debugged the proces from the `server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen())` down to the `ChatConnector.verifyBotFramework()` where at the end I found it calls `_this.dispatch(req.body, res, next);` (ChatbotConnector.js on line 149) passing only the post body but not the request object itself...

So at a first glance I think this is not possible, I just wanted to be sure that I didn't miss anything...
Thanks,
Luis

Comment: I don't think BotBuilder framework exposes that kind of data. Just ask the user for locale(*pronunciation*), when he interacts with the bot for the first time, and save the response in `session.privateConversationData`. For subsequent visit by the user, get the locale info from `session.privateConversationData`. You can also save in `session.userData`, etc... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-state

Comment: This document gives an example of how to prompt the user for locale info  =>  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-localization

Comment: Which channel you are using?

Comment: I'm using WebChat.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, this isn't supported by the Bot Framework, however I don't see why you need to do it this way. This is something you want to store in the state, for example the `userData`. You can read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-state) about [managing state in the Bot Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-state).

If you want to pass user data to the bot, it depends on the channel. For example Facebook and Webchat allow you to pass data direct to the bot, without user input.